# flake8 configuration error setup_flymake.py

Tags: python, emacs

With python and elpy modes, I have just recently started getting the error

```
Flymake: Configuration error has occurred while running (flake8 /<path>/setup_flymake.py). Flymake will be switched OFF
```

I have been working in the particular  for quite a long time and have never had a setup_flymake.py file, and there still is not one in .

Versions are:
emacs-x86_64-10_9
python-mode (standard)
elpy 20150226.1148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently pep8 version >= 1.6 broke a number of things. flake8 itself is in a [quandary](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/51) about what to do about it until pep8 is fixed.

In the meantime, forcing pep8<=1.6.0 is the answer.

Comment: `pip uninstall pep8` also fixed it (too lazy to figure out how to pin a pip package version when using an "upgrade all pips" script)